# Binding formGroup using HostBiinding in the component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I tried to bind my formgroup from the host attribute in the component, but it returns an error

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form[random-form]',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'random-form.component.html',
  host: {"class": "random", "(document:click)" : "onDocumentClick($event)",
        "[formGroup]" : "form"}
})
export class RandomForm implements OnInit {
    form : FormGroup;
}
```

it returns an error

```
zone.js:643 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
```

This is how i call the component

```
<form random-form>
    </form>
```

I have import ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule too in the app.module.ts and the subsequent module. I am pretty sure this is a problem with host, because if i put it in the template, it will work

Comment: I think it won't work.

Comment: You can make it an injectable for the component. Which will raise an error if a developer doesn't apply the `[formGroup]` when using your component. Otherwise you'll have to attach it manually.

Answer (score 1):

When one component depends upon another that's when you use dependency injection. This will raise an error if the component can't be found in the DOM (unless you mark it as `@Optional`).

```
public constructor(formGroup: FormGroupDirective) {
}
```

You can't use host bindings to create other components. I wish we could but I suspect this would raise more problems when there is collision between the existing DOM components and the host bindings.

You can create components at run-time relatively easily with Angular 4.x, and add a FormGroup if one isn't found.

```
public constructor(@Optional() public formGroup: FormGroupDirective,
                   public factory: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                   public view: ViewContainerRef) {
}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(!this.formGroup) {
         this.formGroup = this.view.createComponent(this.factory.resolveComponentFactory(FormGroupDirective));
        this.formGroup.form = /*** build your form here **/
    }
}
```

Now, I have no idea if the above will work with a directive. I've never used `createComponent` to create a directive before. Since directives don't have templates I'm not sure the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be the solution for u.

template.html

```
    <form [formGroup] = "myForm" (ngSubmit) = "submitForm(myForm.value)">
         <input type="password"  id="password" value="{{password}}" formControlName="password" />
         <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

component.ts

```
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

export class RandomForm implements OnInit {
    myForm : FormGroup;
    password: string = "";

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
             password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)]]
        });
    }

    submitForm(value) {
       //you can get the values or the myForm here like this value.password;
    }
}
```